# Codelite program will not run

Tags: c++, error-handling, build, codelite

I'm trying to run a program on Codelite and it runs fine on my PC but on my mac I keep getting the error message below
[image]

the output window says

Current working directory: /Users/me/Desktop/Class/Converter1/Debug
Running program: /usr/bin/open /Applications/codelite.app/Contents/MacOS/codelite-terminal.app --args  --exit  --wait  --working-directory "/Users/me/Desktop/Class/Converter1/Debug/" --title "./Converter1 " --cmd ./Converter1
Program exited with return code: 0

I looked around and saw people having similar problems and one person mentioned that if there was a space in the path it wouldn't work but I don't think there is. I'm not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of CodeLite?, if not sure, make sure you are using the latest weekly build of OSX: http://downloads.codelite.org

Disable the built-in terminal emulator (so CodeLite will use Terminal.app instead)  CodeLite->Global Editor Preferences->Terminal->Use CodeLite builtin terminal emulator?

These two steps should fix your problem

Eran